# Java-Como conseguir que un elemento no se repita en un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que tengo que hacer una serie de preguntas en un array list y si hay alguna respuesta que se repita no la debo mostrar, como puedo conseguir que no se me repita? Tengo un objeto con dos variables y realizo 2 preguntas (1 para cada variable) en bucle mientras el usuario quiera seguir introduciendo datos, si una de las 2 respuestas coincide con alguna de las 2 respuestas insertadas anteriormente solo debe enseñar una.

este es mi main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        //llamamos al metodo
        getEmpleados();
    }

    public static void getEmpleados() {
        //creamos el array list de empleados
        ArrayList <Empleado> empleados = new ArrayList<Empleado>();

        String nombre;
        String sueldo;
        String respuesta;

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        //realizamos la pregunta por primera vez
        System.out.println("Cual es tu nombre?");
        nombre = lector.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Cual es tu sueldo?");
        sueldo = lector.nextLine();
        empleados.add(new Empleado(nombre,sueldo));

        //empezamos un bucle mientras el usuario desee insertar mas usuarios
        do {    
            System.out.println("Quieres insertar los datos de algun empleado mas?(S/N)");
            respuesta = lector.nextLine();

            //si la respuesta es s volvera a preguntar nombre y suelo sino dirá gracias
            if (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                System.out.println("Cual es tu nombre?");
                nombre = lector.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Cual es tu sueldo?");
                sueldo = lector.nextLine();

                empleados.add(new Empleado(nombre,sueldo));

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Gracias");
            }

        }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")); //mientras la respuesta sea s

        //imprimimos el listado de empleados el array list es recorrido por un for
        System.out.println("\n**Empleados**");
        for(Empleado e: empleados) {

            if (e.getNombre() == e.getNombre() && e.getSueldo() == e.getSueldo() || e.getNombre() == e.getNombre() || e.getSueldo() == e.getSueldo()  ) {
            System.out.println("\n"+e.getEmpleado());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

He tratado de realizar que no se repitan realizando en el for un if else sin mucho exito

Comment: Tendrías que subir lo que hayas intentando para poder ayudarte.

Comment: vale voy a subirlo :)

Comment: ¿Qué elemento quieres que no se repita? ¿El nombre del empleado?

Comment: ni el nombre ni el sueldo deben repetirse, me pide que no debe visualizarse informacion repetida,solo se verá la informacion del primero, he cambiado el arraylist por hashset pero sigue repitiendome toda la informacion

Comment: El ejercicio dice: No se visualizara información repetida, és decir, si hay diversos empleados que ganan lo mismo o que se llaman igual o las dos cosas, solo se visualizara la información del primero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Java-Como conseguir que un elemento no se repita en un ArrayList?

Puedes hacer uso del método [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) de la clase `ArrayList`, en la cual servirá para saber si el objeto existe en la lista. Este método retornará `true` si el objeto se encuentra en el `ArrayList`, de lo contrario, devuelve `false`.

Sin embargo, deberás [sobreescribir](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) (realizar cierta modificación a un método heredado de una clase, en este caso de [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)) el método [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) en la clase `Empleado`, debido a que, el método `contains` internamente invocará este método para poder comparar los objetos.

Ahora vamos a imaginar que la clase `Empleado` fue definido de esta manera y adicionalmente añadiremos el método `equals` al final de la clase:

```
class Empleado
{
    private String nombre;
    private String sueldo;

    public Empleado(String nombre, String sueldo)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }

    public String getNombre(){ return nombre; }
    public String getSueldo(){ return sueldo; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if(o == null) return false;
        Empleado emp = (Empleado)o;
       //Se compara los atributos de ambos objetos
        return (sueldo.equalsIgnoreCase(emp.sueldo)) || (nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(emp.nombre));
    }
}
```

Por último solo faltaría invocar el método `contains` antes del método `add`. Es decir, solo vamos añadir un objeto en la lista, siempre y cuando, el objeto no se encuentra en el `ArrayList`.

```
//si la respuesta es s volvera a preguntar nombre y suelo sino dirá gracias
if (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) 
{
    System.out.println("Cual es tu nombre?");
    nombre = lector.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Cual es tu sueldo?");
    sueldo = lector.nextLine();
    //Creamos el objeto de tipo Empleado
    Empleado emp = new Empleado(nombre, sueldo);
    //Verificamos si el objeto se encuentra en la lista y si es verdad, lo añadimos en la lista
    if(empleados.contains(emp) == false)
        empleados.add(emp);         
}
```

Y de este modo, nunca tendrás una información repetida.

También había código redundante, porqué primero pides información por primera vez y después lo vuelves hacer en el do-while, cuando en realidad todo puede ir en el bucle.

El código sin la redundancia quedaría de esta forma:

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        //llamamos al metodo
        getEmpleados();
    }

    public static void getEmpleados() {
        //creamos el array list de empleados
        ArrayList <Empleado> empleados = new ArrayList<Empleado>();

        String nombre;
        String sueldo;
        String respuesta;

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        //empezamos un bucle mientras el usuario desee insertar mas usuarios
        do {    
            System.out.println("Cual es tu nombre?");
            nombre = lector.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Cual es tu sueldo?");
            sueldo = lector.nextLine();
            //Creamos el objeto de tipo Empleado
            Empleado emp = new Empleado(nombre, sueldo);
            //Verificamos si el objeto se encuentra en la lista y si es verdad, lo añadimos en la lista
            if(empleados.contains(emp) == false)
                empleados.add(emp);

            System.out.println("Quieres insertar los datos de algun empleado mas?(S/N)");
            respuesta = lector.nextLine();  

            if(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
            {
                System.out.println("Gracias");
                break;//rompemos el ciclo do-while
            }

        }while(true); //mientras la respuesta sea s
        //Se imprime la lista
        for(Empleado emp : empleados)
        {
            System.out.println("Nombre: " + emp.getSueldo() + "\nSueldo: " + emp.getNombre());
        }
    }   
}
```

**EDIT:**

Esta condicional no tiene sentido:

```
if (e.getNombre() == e.getNombre() && e.getSueldo() == e.getSueldo() || e.getNombre() == e.getNombre() || e.getSueldo() == e.getSueldo()  )
```

Porqué básicamente estarías comparando los atributos de un mismo objeto y por lo tanto, la condición siempre dará como resultado un `true` y esa es la razón del porqué no te funciona.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias justo era eso :)